# Como desencadeno un 'Refrescar' en un RecyclerView?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, recyclerview, xamarin.android

Estoy cargando un `RecyclerView` con 3 listas de `string`, la distribución actual del Recycler es la siguiente:

-Titulo (Ejemplo: Reunion de padres)

-Contenido (Ejemplo: La reunion es mañana)

-FechaHora (Ejemplo: 12/12/2020 - 10:00am)

Entonces tengo estas 3 listas digamos así:

Titulo [Reunion de padres, Reunion de hijos, Reunion de profesores].

Al abrir el layout donde tengo el RecyclerView se dispara el evento `OnBindViewHolder` (codigo a continuacion):

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            try
            { 
            FeedViewHolder hh = holder as FeedViewHolder;

            hh.txtTitle.Text = VarGlobal.NFTitulo[position];
            hh.txtPubDate.Text = VarGlobal.NFFechaHora[position];
            hh.txtContent.Text = VarGlobal.NFContenido[position];    
                
            hh.itemClickListener = this;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

**Y me carga los 3 titulos que tengo actualmente sin problema.**

El problema esta en que también puedo seguir agregando elementos a las listas en el mismo layout y esos elementos no me aparecen luego de haber sido agregados, entonces viene quedando digamos de la siguiente forma:

Titulo [Reunion de padres, Reunion de hijos, Reunion de profesores, ***Reunion de finalización***].

Entonces como les decía, el RecyclerView no actualiza, no muestra el o los elementos nuevos, solo los 3 titulos originales, y no se como desencadenar el evento OnBindViewHolder correctamente nuevamente, o el evento que se tenga que desencadenar para actualizar el Recycler.

Lo que necesito es que me refresque el adapter y me cargue todos los Títulos nuevamente sin tener que reiniciar la app.

Ideas?

Comment: si quieres actualizar tu lista, necesitas llamar al método notifyDataSetChange() del adapter una vez has actualizado tu lista